# How to show desktop application launchers only in a certain desktop environment?

Tags: gnome, xfce

I use Gnome and Xfce sessions, but whereas in Gnome I have application shortcuts on the panel, in Xfce I prefer having application launchers on the desktop.

I don't need the desktop launcher in Gnome, so I would like to have them hidden in the Ubuntu Classic session. I tried to append the `OnlyShowIn=XFCE` option at the bottom of the `.desktop` files in the Desktop folder, but to no avail.

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *OnlyShowIn* tag controls what launchers appear in menus. The launchers themselves (eg 'firefox.desktop') are just files and will appear in their relevant folders regardless of your desktop environment.

To prevent Nautilus from showing files (and thus, launchers) on the GNOME Desktop:

1. Launch `gconf-editor`
2. Navigate to `apps > nautilus > preferences`
3. Untick the `show_desktop` option

Comment: Not true, it works also with `show_desktop` set true, though needing a nautilus refresh.